# Connetion to database PHP (empty database)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sorry, but i ve got another problem... with connection, I guess.
I try to delete record, but my database is empty. And look like this:

[image: screenshot]

And this is the code. I know, this probably trivial matter but I'm amateur in PHP.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kluby ranking");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM europa";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete data in mysql</strong> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Nacja</strong></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>LiczbaPkt</strong></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['ID']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['Nacja']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['LiczbaPkt']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="usuw2.php?ID=<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>">delete</a></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    // close while loop 
    }
    ?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kluby ranking");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['ID'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM europa WHERE ID='ID'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
    echo "Deleted Successfully";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='usuw.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I think your last query is wrong. `DELETE FROM europa WHERE ID='ID'`. Probably want that in a conditional and using a variable. You then will want to use a parameterized query...or are these 2 different scripts?

Comment: `WHERE ID='ID'";` that should read as `WHERE ID='$id'";` and don't close your connection before that. Matter 'o fact, you don't even need to close it, MySQL will do it on its own.

Comment: Yes, you have 'ID' field name, but you search for **value** of 'ID' file... BTW, what means ‘empty database’? Your db is empty or the query returns no results? If your database is really empty, how can you think of deleting rows?

Comment: No my database have records . The query returns no results

Comment: I change ID to '$id'" and still nothing

Comment: You have to check errors, man. Check if the connection is ok, then check the result returned by the query. If the result is empty, try your query through phpMyAdmin to see if the problem reside in it